# Change default browser for debugging ASP.NET app in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: asp.net, macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

I'm new to MacOS and I installed VS for Mac as it was my main IDE on Windows. But I can't find where I can use Chrome or Firefox to debug ASP.NET Application instead of Safari. (I don't want to set another browser as my default one via MacOS Settings)

Is there a way to change this without changing the OS default browser ? (Like in Windows)

Answer (score 0):

There is an additional Visual Studio extension that I have used earlier this year when I went through a short stint in using Visual Studio on my Mac. The plugin is called [Open In Browser](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=techer.open-in-browser).

That extension might be of use to you.